# Проблема с кодировкой при импорте из MySQL в Google Datastudio

Tags: php, mysql, sql, php7, google-data-studio

Всем привет!
Возникла проблема с кодировкой при подключении мой MySQL к Google Datastudio.

Через php данные заливаю в БД. В конфиге my.cnf прописано:

```
[mysqld]
# Require clients to connect either using SSL
# or through a local socket file
require_secure_transport = ON
bind-address = 0.0.0.0

skip-character-set-client-handshake
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8;'
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci

[client]
default-character-set = utf8

[mysqldump]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld_safe]
default-character-set = utf8
```

При выводе кодировок в самой БД `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Однако, во-первых, при выводе данных через терминал, результат такой:

```
| 20012 | 2018-04-06 | 11106169 | ÐÐ´Ð¼Ð¸Ð½ | ...
```

Ну и при подключении этой БД к Google Data studio, результат такой:

[image: Вывод данных в GDS]

В чем может быть проблема и куда копать? Заранее спасибо за помощь!

UPD:
Заметил такую картину в базе: некоторые русские символы распознаются нормально, вот пример:

[image: Пример отображения имени Админа в базе]

Однако остальные имена так и остались в неверной кодировке. Подскажите, может быть в PHP-коде, который данные в базу заливает есть ошибка?

Comment: Возможно тебе стоит сменить приложение, с которого ты это все просматриваешь. У меня было такое, исправил тем что смотрел все через файл

Comment: @ИванТихонов
Спасибо, но тут к сожалению смена сервиса невозможна(

Comment: Я в DataStudio беру данный из MySql. Данные в таблице в MySql в utf8_unicode_ci.
Отображаются на русском, но фильтры не работают. Вы смогли за год решить задачу?

Comment: Где-то на просторах интернета нашел, что DataStudio «криво» работает с кодировками, поэтому пошли самым простым путем и сделали транслитерацию русских слов в английские на входе.